# Mono 5.14.0 and TLS 1.2 "No such TLS Provider btls"

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, tls1.2, libtls

If I connect to an **TLS 1.0 - 1.2** endpoint with a HttpClient and **Mono 5.14.0** I get the exception "No such TLS Provider: `btls`."

```
No such TLS Provider: `btls'.
at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsProviderFactory.LookupProvider (System.String name, System.Boolean throwOnError)
as Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsProviderFactory.CreateDefaultProviderImpl ()
at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsProviderFactory.InitializeInternal ()
```

If I change the TLS Provider to legacy I can only connect to an Endpoint with TLS 1.0, an Endpoint with TLS 1.0 - 1.2 doesn't work.

```
MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=legacy
```

I don't understand how the provider blts is unknown, since Mono 4.8.0 is the provider btls from the BoringSSL project included. see [here](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/).

If I take a look at [MonoTlsProviderFactory.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/4c8d3505ed5bad8ef1c8b7e355a8cc257b3e2f1b/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoTlsProviderFactory.cs) to understand this behavior, I stumble upon the line, which I don't understand.

```
internal extern static bool IsBtlsSupported ();
```

see [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/4c8d3505ed5bad8ef1c8b7e355a8cc257b3e2f1b/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoTlsProviderFactory.cs#L297) and there is the `MONO_FEATURE_BTLS` symbol which is a condition for btls. But How can I know if my Mono version is compiled with this symbol?

There are similar cases but with an older Mono version

- [Mono issue with TLS due to Client Certificates #6498](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/6498)
- [Bug 53912 [Client Certificates] Server requests TLS Renegotiation](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53912)
- [[Client Certificates] TLS Renegotiation for client certificates](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43332)

Comment: Does your Mono's bistro include a `Mono.Btls.Interface` assembly in the GAC?

Comment: @SushiHangover how can I proof this?

Comment: It may have been updated, but I do recall mono not supporting TLS 1.2 a couple of years ago. I used a small node.js reverse proxy in my solution to allow my mono app to call out to a TLS1.2-only endpoint on the web. Not pretty.